# Spam pop-up in every browser

Tags: windows-7, browser, malware, spam-prevention

When I'm browsing on the web—regardless of the browser—once in a while there is a pop-up in the bottom left corner.

[image: popup window]

I tried scanning the computer with Ad-Aware & malwarebyte.org but that didn't solve the problem.

When I right click on that Spam block, sometimes i get a menu with copyright information. The copyright says it belongs to "DSNR Media Group".

Comment: Describe the pop-up in more detail.  It sounds unassociated with your browser and is possibly an infection your computer has.  Try investigating your computer with the MalwareBytes software.  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

Comment: I suggest you give a screenshot. "A popup" is quite vague.

Comment: Usually a pop-up within a browswer is from the javascript downloaded from a particular site that is then active. Note which site you are both visiting and just changed from, when the popup occurs. Also make sure your browser has popups disabled.

Comment: A screenshot can be found at: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/spamdy.jpg/) , the OS of the computer: Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: @JoshDM The scan with malwarebytes.org didn't help, anymore ideas?

Comment: Is it the same one everytime? If it is, try blocking that site USACG.org? from opening popups.

Comment: Does this occur on *every* website? If so, it's probably some malware you have installed that is under the radar of the malware detectors. Look in Add & Remove Programs for anything suspicious. Have you installed any trialware/freeware lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the "popup" is XP themed and your version of Windows is using the Aero theme it is obviously not an actual popup generated by the browser or a program, but a website's "trick" popup. As @jdh said, it is most likely a javascript or similar active content "feature". If you want to get rid of it, look into ad blockers such as AdBlock Plus or NoScript.

Comment: I am well familiar with the popups in the screen caps you posted.  I can tell you with certainty that Adblock+ in Firefox stops them dead.  Internet Explorer on the other hand, I've never found a way to eliminate them short of totally disabling java script and Active-X.  Good luck

Comment: The combination of the 2 adblockers did the job! thank you very much!

Comment: @OCDtech: While it's not perfect and *nowhere* close to what AB+ can do, Tracking Protection in IE using EasyList or Fanboy's List (same as AB+ uses) will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If these popups appear in every browser and random websites which usually don't have these popups, that's crystal clear: you got a malware.

Too bad the software you tried didn't detect it. Report it to the publisher, they'll be happy to eradicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ad-Blocker add-in on all the browsers. I got the similar issue on my system. After researching many articles i have installed the add-on and tried and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

Search through your PC's hard drive and delete the following files:

> TagEditionOperations.java
>   LyricsContent_java.sample
>   AutoSetLyricsAction.java